# Asterisk sound on desktop

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, desktop

Is it normal to hear the “windows asterisk” sound when you press a key on the keyboard while on the desktop? I do not hear this sound in safe mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could be hearing a sound with each key press because the OS is alerting you that your keypresses are being blocked/lost. Normally, keypresses when the focus is on the desktop select the first desktop item that starts with the pressed letter. If there is no matching item, Windows produces 1 system beep.

What you are hearing could be caused by a full keyboard buffer, or by an open alert box or dialog box that has the system focus. However, these cases would typically produce the "Default Beep" or "Critical Stop" sound, not necessarily the Asterisk. By default, Asterisk is mapped to "Windows Error.wav" on many (all?) Win systems.

It is possible that there is a window you are not seeing because it is behind another window, or "offscreen" on a second or phantom monitor. You need to investigate where the focus really is, what application or alerts are actually open. Try opening Notepad and typing that window. Are the keystrokes accepted? If not, then the "other window has focus" is very likely.